# Pandas Adding Phantom Columns

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames `src, dst` for a transfer learning task in bioinformatics, one has labels, the other does not. What I want to do is make sure that *outside of the labeling and ID columns* they share the same features in the same order for putting into numpy.

Specifically:

the columns for `src` are  `['PATIENT_ID','SAMPLE_ID', <buncha_stuff1>, "SUBTYPE","SUBTYPE_SHORT","LABEL"]`

and `['PATIENT_ID','SAMPLE_ID', <buncha_stuff2>]` for `dst`.

The `buncha stuff` is not the same in both but there is a large intersection. My goal is to take `buncha_stuff = buncha_stuff1.intersection(buncha_stuff2)` and use that as the non-label and non-id columns in `src` and `dst`. My approach is

```
meta_cols ={"PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID","SUBTYPE","SUBTYPE_SHORT","LABEL"}
common_genes= list(set(src.columns).intersection(set(dst.columns))-meta_cols)
src_cols = ["PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID"] + common_genes + ["SUBTYPE","SUBTYPE_SHORT","LABEL"]
dst_cols = ["PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID"] + common_genes
src = src[src_cols]
dst = dst[dst_cols]
```

At the beginning `src` has 18605 columns and `dst` has 17666. The list`src_cols` has length 17651 and `dst_cols` has length 17648, however when I check the data frame shapes after doing

```
src = src[src_cols]
dst = dst[dst_cols]
```

`src` has 17672 columns and `dst` has 17666.

it seems like pandas is just adding in columns and I can't find them? what is going on? I'm going insane

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some of the columns names are duplicated. Using `src[src_cols]` would return any column with a column name in the `src_cols` list even if they were duplicates.

A quick check is: `len(set(src.columns)) - len(src.columns)`. If this is `!=0` then there must be duplicates. Hopefully it will return the number of additional columns you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes total sense to me however, you could use another approach to verify what's going on:

```
meta_cols =["PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID","SUBTYPE","SUBTYPE_SHORT","LABEL"]
src_cols = src.columns
dst_cols = dst.columns
common_genes= list(set(set(src_cols) and set(dst_cols)))
common_genes = [x for x in common_genes if x not in meta_cols]
src_cols = ["PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID"] + common_genes + ["SUBTYPE","SUBTYPE_SHORT","LABEL"]
dst_cols = ["PATIENT_ID","SAMPLE_ID"] + common_genes
src = src[src_cols]
dst = dst[dst_cols]
```